# Send push notification to iOS without a native app?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I have an external service (a website), and would like to be able to send myself a push notification to my iPhone when certain events require my attention (e.g. webserver crash, when fraud is detected etc).

Is there some Apple API built for this use case, that is, for an external service to create a push notification to iOS *without* developing a native iOS app for that very purpose?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, you must have an app to send notifications.